# Detect browser if capable/enabled for http2 via javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, http2, spdy

I've checked on similar questions and found two options I can proceed with, however both have problematic issues.

```
if ( performance && performance.timing.nextHopProtocol ) {
    console.log('Protocol:' + performance.timing.nextHopProtocol);
} else if ( window.chrome && window.chrome.loadTimes ) {
console.log('Protocol:' + window.chrome.loadTimes().connectionInfo);
} else {
    console.log("Browser does not expose connection protocol");
}
```

The above code does return the protocol however, while using my chrome **it supports http2** and is **capable**, but still returns http1.

On another solution is to compile a list of supported browsers and cross check the http_useragent, however the list should be checked in from time to time and also cross check the OS versions. since for example IE 11 on windows 10 works but for let's say lower version it wont.

Comment: So.. let's say you do detect that browser is HTTP/2 capable, what then? What do you do with that information? I'm asking out of curiosity, it might be you're onto something useful so if you are, I'd like to see what it might be :)

Comment: I'm basically trying to replicate this page. https://http2.akamai.com/demo however their http2 detection is their proprietary service I believe. I'm working for a web hosting company so we're setting up comparison pages for http2 upgrades. already done with everything else except this.

Comment: reading [this](https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2015/08/25/under-the-covers-of-the-http2-performance-demo-on-http2akamaicomdemo) they do the check server side, not on front.

Comment: @Kaiido yea server side + they have their own service for that "Akamai's Edge Side Includes". So I'm looking for any other stuff I can use. php is fine too.

Comment: The protocol depends on the server so `performance.getEntriesByType('resource')` wouldn't help.